# Print a score counter with HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, real-time

I am having the following logic in my code. When someone clicks a button on a button, I increment a score counter by one. I want to print this value in the html side, at the very next second. What are my optios? I have tried the following(score is a div in the html side and score the global counter) with no result:

```
document.getElementById("score").innerHTML+=score;

var tmpscore = document.getElementById("score");
tmpscore.appendChild(score);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `score`? A number, a div? Is that code inside the button handler or where do you call it?

Comment: There is a click handler, and score is a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var score_elem = document.getElementById("score");
score_elem.innerHTML = parseInt(score_elem.innerHTML)++;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using jQuery, you could do `document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = tempscore;`